# What is the alternative to "NOT IN" in HQL Query?

Tags: hql

Below is the query in SQL

> SELECT * FROM `table_1`  WHERE    `table_1_id` NOT IN (       SELECT
>   table_1_id FROM `table_2`         WHERE `some_other_id` =
>   '81ae4876-52fe-4dcf-9a5e-8eb490176d46'    )

Comment: Why would you need an alternative? What's wrong with "not in"?